# Unable to pass a Seq[String] to .parquet in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to read multiple paths in one call within the Spark API in Scala, with the `.parquet` method.

I've got a method which receives a `Seq[String]` but seems to be unable to recognize it when included in the method call and tries to retrieve a `String` instead of a `Seq[String]`.

```
def readPaths(sparkSession: SparkSession, basePath: String, inputPaths: Seq[String]): Dataset[Row] = {
  sparkSession.read
    .option("basepath", basePath)
    .parquet(inputPaths) // Doesn't accept 'inputPaths'
```

}

In the commented part, it just complains about `Seq[String]` not being a `String` type object, meanwhile it does accept a plain `"", "", "", ""`.

Comment: As soon as written in the IDE it just pops up the error, I don't even compile the code. The `.parquet` method shows a `Cannot resolve overloaded method 'parquet'`, and then if I mouseover the `inputPath` as method parameter it says `Type mismatch, expected: String, actual: Seq[String]`. Using Spark 2.2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The:

```
def parquet(paths: String*): DataFrame
```

[method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@parquet-scala.collection.Seq-) expect a varargs, not explicitely a Seq. For this reason, in Scala you must pass it as:

```
    def readPaths(sparkSession: SparkSession, basePath: String, inputPaths: Seq[String]): Dataset[Row] = {
  sparkSession.read
    .option("basepath", basePath)
    .parquet(inputPaths:_*)
  }
```

please, note the ":_*" at the end of your val.

Verified on a spark2-shell (with Spark 2.3.0.cloudera3):

```
scala> case class MyProduct(key: Int, value: String, lastSeen: java.sql.Timestamp)
defined class MyProduct

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> val baseDS = spark.createDataset(0 until 1000).map(i => MyProduct(i, s"valueOf:$i", new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())))
baseDS: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[MyProduct] = [key: int, value: string ... 1 more field]

scala> baseDS.withColumn("state", lit("IT"))
res10: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: int, value: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> res10.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("state").parquet("/tmp/test/parquet/")

scala> baseDS.withColumn("state", lit("US"))
res12: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: int, value: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> res12.write.mode("append").partitionBy("state").parquet("/tmp/test/parquet/")

scala> val inputPaths = Seq("/tmp/test/parquet/state=IT", "/tmp/test/parquet/state=US")
inputPaths: Seq[String] = List(/tmp/test/parquet/state=IT, /tmp/test/parquet/state=US)

scala> val data = spark.read.parquet(inputPaths)
<console>:38: error: overloaded method value parquet with alternatives:
  (paths: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (path: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (Seq[String])
       val data = spark.read.parquet(inputPaths)
                             ^

scala> val data = spark.read.parquet(inputPaths:_*)
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: int, value: string ... 1 more field]

scala> data.show(10)
+---+-----------+--------------------+
|key|      value|            lastSeen|
+---+-----------+--------------------+
|500|valueOf:500|2019-02-04 17:05:...|
|501|valueOf:501|2019-02-04 17:05:...|
|502|valueOf:502|2019-02-04 17:05:...|
|503|valueOf:503|2019-02-04 17:05:...|
|504|valueOf:504|2019-02-04 17:05:...|
|505|valueOf:505|2019-02-04 17:05:...|
|506|valueOf:506|2019-02-04 17:05:...|
|507|valueOf:507|2019-02-04 17:05:...|
|508|valueOf:508|2019-02-04 17:05:...|
|509|valueOf:509|2019-02-04 17:05:...|
+---+-----------+--------------------+
only showing top 10 rows


scala>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the `parquet()` function is expecting a "varargs" argument, i.e. one or more arguments of type `String`.

You can pass it a `Seq[String]` but you must give the compiler a hint to tell it to unpack the Seq into multiple arguments.

An example to demonstrate the usage of varargs:

```
scala> def foo(i: String*) = i.mkString(",")
foo: (i: String*)String

scala> foo("a", "b", "c")
res0: String = a,b,c

scala> foo(Seq("a", "b", "c"))
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[String]
 required: String
       foo(Seq("a", "b", "c"))
              ^

scala> foo(Seq("a", "b", "c"):_*)
res2: String = a,b,c
```

As you can see the `:_*` hint fixes the problem.